# Soft 404, Fetch and Render showing js bundle temporarily unreachable

Tags: 404, fetch-as-google, soft-404

We recently launched a new page to our site. Previously our whole site has been in classic asp and this page is an angular SPA with asp.net on the backend.

Since the launch of the new page our amount of soft 404s have dramatically increased with most being on this page.

[image: Soft 404s on the rise]

After running the google fetch and render 20 times, there were two instances when the JS bundle (bundled by asp.net) returned as temporarily unreachable for the google bot.

[image: temporarily unreachable]

I've gone through the IIS logs pretty closely searching for these bundles during the time I was testing and they all returned a 200 status code.

What can I do to debug this further? Why would the bundle be temporarily unreachable?

Is this empty page that is happening about 10% of the time by the google bots responsible for the soft 404s?

Answer (score 1):

A check of the Google Product forum encountered someone who had a similar issue.

The issue was that the site was returning an `x-robots-tag` HTTP header specifying not to index the page. This is often a technical quirk or a wrong setting somewhere in your server configuration. Once the HTTP header is removed it should settle back down on its own over time.

Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/g8yeYtcNo8A/discussion